# How to get multiple placemarks from CLGeocoder

Tags: core-location, clgeocoder

Whatever address i give to the geocoder ([geocoder geocodeAddressString:completionHandler:), it always puts only one object in the placemarks array.

I there any way to get multiple results (like in Maps app) from which the user can select one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've done some sniffing on the packets and it seems that CLGeocoder doesn't connect to Google's geocoding service, but to Apple's. I've also noticed that I get only one placemark from there every time.

If you want something more sophisticated you should use Google's or other geocoding. I use [SVGeocoder (https://github.com/samvermette/SVGeocoder)](https://github.com/samvermette/SVGeocoder), which has a very similar API to CLGeocoder.

Comment: Why does this happen? From the Apple Docs: In the case of forward-geocoding requests, multiple placemark objects may be returned if the provided information yielded multiple possible locations.

Comment: I suppose Apple's geocoding service is pretty limited as of now. I would expect it to change soonish. You can see that Apple is just rushing to move away from dependence on Google here.

Comment: It's interesting as there still seem to be issues with multiple `placemark` returns from CLGeocoder although the iOS 6 native maps search solution seems to implement exactly what everyone is looking for.  I wonder what solution Apple are using themselves at the moment

Comment: SVGeocoder uses the Google geocoder service which you can not use without displaying the results on a google map by the way.

Answer (score 11):

Apple's native geocoding service is provided by the [**MapKit framework**](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MapKit_Framework_Reference/_index.html). The important object in this framework is `MKLocalSearch`, which can geocode addresses and return multiple results.

MKLocalSearch returns back 10 results in `mapItems` of type `MKMapItem`. Each MKMapItem contains a `MKPlacemark` object, which is a subclass of `CLPlacemark`.

Here's an example using MapKit's `MKLocalSearch`:

```
MKLocalSearchRequest* request = [[MKLocalSearchRequest alloc] init];
request.naturalLanguageQuery = @"Calgary Tower";
request.region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(loc, kSearchMapBoundingBoxDistanceInMetres, kSearchMapBoundingBoxDistanceInMetres);

MKLocalSearch* search = [[MKLocalSearch alloc] initWithRequest:request];
[search startWithCompletionHandler:^(MKLocalSearchResponse *response, NSError *error) {
   yourArray = response.mapItems; // array of MKMapItems
   // .. do you other logic here  
 }];
```